# Data integrity checksum for file transfer with scp from local system to a flash drive connected on a remote computer

Tags: remote-server, checksum, data-integrity, data-corruption

I am trying to check data integrity for a file transferred from local system to flash drive connected on a remote system.

So couple of questions:

1. Is scp good method to transfer files this way? I cannot transfer file directory to remote system but only on an external flash drive connected to it.
2. I am using sha 256 for checksum to avoid collision to a great extend. Is this checksum a good option?
3. So overall test is, get checksum for file on local system using Windows Powershell and then find checksum on remote system which is linux based. If they match then I am good to go.

Is there any better approach or suggestions to verify data corruption while moving a file from local system to a flash drive connected on remote system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

0. Ask one question, not many
1. yes, `scp` is quite good software for this purpose. You can use also `sftp`
2. yes, `sha256` is very good hashing algorithm
3. There are other solutions too like rsync, but if this is fine for you and work well do not change it.